# How to count meta_key(s) of a page?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, count, meta

Is it possible to count the amount of the same meta_keys for the same post_id.

I have a page with the post_id 44 and every time a user submits something on this page a new database rule is added with the meta_key "post_rating_0".

There are over 30 rules now for this page and I want to count them.
For other pages the same thing.

Is this possible?

**Code so far:**

```
global $post;
$query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key' => 'post_rating_0'
            // 'fields' => 'SUM(amount_to_paid)',
        );

$sum = 0;
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do the processing for each post
        $sum = $sum + intval(get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'post_rating_0', true ));
    }
}
echo $sum ;
```

This is what I got so far... But what this does is echo the value of "2" what is very logic. It searches for posts with the meta_key "post_rating_0", counts them and that are 2 posts.

What I'm trying to do is count the amount of meta_keys "post_rating_0" are in one page.

Comment: please show us the code where "post_rating_0" shows up

Comment: I edited my aswer with the code I got so far but that is not counting the meta_keys that are there for a specific page

Comment: So you want to know the amount of all `post_rating_0` meta for each `post_id`? Like an array?

Comment: You should perhaps rather use a custom query, so that you can do the counting in the query directly, and don’t have to loop over all the records afterwards. And you simply limit it to the specific page you are interested in by specifying the post id of that page in the WHERE clause.

Comment: If you want the _number_ of entries, then why are you summing up the _values_?

Comment: @mitkosoft Yes, exactly like that

Comment: @CBroe, I though this will work but when I was done I realised this is not the way to do it. And because I dont know how to do it I asked for help to get me started

Comment: @user2812779, please check is that specific ID meets your query arguments (page, published etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This modified code will give you an array with all `post_id` and the corresponding amount of your specific meta:

```
$meta_arr = array();
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_id();
        $meta_arr[$post_id] = intval(get_post_meta($post_id, 'post_rating_0', false));
    }
}

print_r($meta_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this does the exact same thing as before. I got this out of it: Array ( [343] => 1 [44] => 1 ). 343 is a page_id and 44 is a page_id. So result is 2 again. I want to count the meta_key with "post_rating_0" of the pages. I know page_id got over 30 rows with meta_key "post_rating_0"

Comment: @user2812779, what is the `post_type` of this page? are you sure that this specific ID meets your query arguments, i.e. is a page and is published?

Comment: the post_type of the pages are "page" and are published. This is how the database looks like. Just want to count how many time meta_key "post_rating_0" is in page_id 44. https://imgur.com/RqFOc2X

Comment: @user2812779, why the third parameter `of get_post_meta()` is true? try with `false` - see updated code. with `true` the function returns just single value.

Comment: same result... current code is counting posts that  have this meta_key... It has to be exactly the opposite. How many meta_keys with "post_rating_0" has this page.

Answer (score 0):

Did some more research and with some modifications I managed to got it working. This is the final code:

```
                        $pagina_id_test = get_the_id();
                        // retrieve all meta_values with key 'post_rating_0' from database
                        $reviews_posts  = $wpdb->get_results("
                            SELECT meta_value FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta
                            WHERE meta_key = 'post_rating_0'
                            AND post_id = $pagina_id_test", ARRAY_A);
                        // define reviews array
                        $reviews_count  = array();

                        // iterate through meta_values, count the occurence of each review
                        foreach ($reviews_posts as $reviews_post) {
                            if (isset($reviews_count[$reviews_post['meta_value']])) {
                                $reviews_count[$reviews_post['meta_value']] = $reviews_count[$reviews_post['meta_value']] + 1;
                            } else {
                                $reviews_count[$reviews_post['meta_value']] = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        // echo results
                        $aantal_reviews = 0;
                        foreach ($reviews_count as $review) {
                            $aantal_reviews++;
                        }
                        echo $aantal_reviews;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;

$c = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(*) as NBR FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
WHERE post_id={$post_id} AND meta_key='post_rating_0' AND 
(SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE ID={$post_id} AND post_type='page') IS NOT NULL");

echo $c->NBR;
```

Select count of post where `post_type` is page and `meta_key`='post_rating_0'